# Apache Avro - Complex type in Avro's Map values

Tags: java, serialization, avro

Can I have a complex type in an Avro's map value?

Example:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "default": null,
  "name": "Student",
  "namespace": "com.schema",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "grades",
        "default": null,
        "type": ["null", {"type": "map", "values": ["null","string", "int"]}]
    }
  ]
}

{"type" : "map", "values" : "Student"}
```

I tried to insert the record creation directly on the values. It's compile and creates the class, but when I try to send a message, I have an exception: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union